# Failed to resolve ivy dependencies: Error downloading com.github.jupyter:jvm-repr:0.4.0

Tags: scala, maven, jvm, sbt, publish

I am learning about SBT compiling and publishing rules. Consider the following example project I set up:

My build.sbt file looks like:

```
name := "example"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.2"

// almond jupyter api
resolvers += "jvm-repr" at "https://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/public/"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.jupyter" % "jvm-repr" % "0.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "sh.almond" %% "jupyter-api" % "0.9.1"
```

My Example.scala file looks like:

```
import almond.interpreter.api.{DisplayData, OutputHandler}

object Example extends App {
    def f1() = {
      DisplayData(
        Map(
          // if we set up an extension for application/myapp+json, first element should be picked
          "application/myapp+json" -> """{"a": "A"}""",
          // else, text/html should be displayed
          "text/html" -> "<b>A</b>"
        )
      )
    }

    println(f1())
}
```

Now in the sbt shell I type:

```
compile; run
```

The output I get:

> DisplayData(Map(application/myapp+json -> {"a": "A"}, text/html ->
>   **A**),Map(),None)

All well and good as it's working as expected.

Now I publish this package locally. In sbt shell I type:

> publishLocal

I get a message that this has been published to

> .ivy2./local/default/example_2.13/0.1

All well and good.

Now I start up an almond.sh kernel to see if I can successfully import my package and use it. But...

I have the following error:

[image]

Why is this happening? The package seemed to compile and build, yet when I publish it it fails. So somehow the resolvers are not getting added to the published package. Could someone please explain to me what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almond you are missing repository: `"https://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/public/"`, which you added in sbt.

Since almond uses [ammonite](http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL) [this should help](https://almond.sh/docs/api-ammonite.html#add-repositories):

```
interp.repositories() ++= Seq(
  coursierapi.MavenRepository
    .of("https://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/public/")
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz, but is there a way to do this through SBT? I essentially want to make a package that users will import into almond. Using this approach they will have to add these lines to the actual notebook.

Comment: No, there isn't. Published library can store name of its dependencies but not the name of repositories they live in, so if you rely on non-standard repository, you have to add it manually to all downstream consumer's resolvers.

Comment: thanks @Mateusz, I managed to manually download the jar and it managed to work!